# Image rotating wide of off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this code here but my image goes way to far right off of my apps screen i want it to kind of be static but still spin in place or maybe just move around a little bit not so much as it does in this code 
any advice would be appreciated , thank you !

```
<script>
var looper;
var degrees = 0;
function rotateAnimation(el,speed){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
        elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")){
        elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
        elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")){
        elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    } else {
        elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
    }
    looper = setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);
    degrees++;
    if(degrees > 359){
        degrees = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
}
</script>
```

html

```
<img id="img1" src="http://s8.postimg.org/h719p5x85/transimage.png" alt="cog1">
<script>rotateAnimation("img1",15);</script>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using css to rotate your image? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the image has a canvas size much larger than the visible portion itself. The rotation happens around the centre of the image so you're seeing the issues in the rotation. If you crop the star out, the problem should be fixed.

Also, would it not be easier to do this with CSS?

```
#img1 {
  transition: 0.7s linear;
}

#img1:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bfvwweah/1/

Edit: Permanent rotation example: http://jsfiddle.net/bfvwweah/3/

Comment: I've added an example above. This is achieved by using keyframes.